# 130.4 is very slow and killing my internet connection

Tags: 13.04

I have 3 computers at home: 2 laptops and 1 desktop.

I have an internet connection of 20mb down and 3 mb up.

After I installed Ubuntu 13.04 (clean install, wiped the HD) on a desktop and a laptop, I see something weird:

1. **The systems are VERY slow** (comparing to 12.10)
2. The biggest problem: **they are taking all my bandwidth** (without any application open). It comes down to ~3 mb down and ~0.5 mb up.

If I turn the systems, the bandwidth is OK.

I don't see these problems on my work laptop (12.04 with gnome-classic), and didn't had them before upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04.

**Any idea what is happening?**

Some details:
The laptop is doal core with 4G of RAM
The desktop if quad core with 8G of RAM
The router id D-Link.

**Edit:**

1. I see the connection problem on the 13.04 mchines AND on the 12.04 mchine (and on my Android phone)
2. The system is slow in opening browser (Firefox), opening folders (Nautilus) and in general.

Comment: Are you saying that the laptops only get ~3 down or are you saying that with the laptops on something else on the network gets only ~3 down.

Comment: Can you specify what you experience as slow? (opening some application, internet, ...)
Can you also say how you notice that they take up all the bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but it seems that your experiencing two different problems.

For the network, you need to isolate the machines from the problem.

1. Turn on both machines
2. Make sure there idle
3. Turn of networking from the network manager indicator
4. Test your network "speed" again. (from some other internet connected device)

If it's better then turn networking on on one machine and test again from the same third device. If it stayed basically the same turn on networking on the second machine. Once you find the problem machine then you can start trying to narrow down that machine. Look for programs or processes downloading data. Apt get may be downloading updates, or dropbox may be syncing.

Finally if you can, on your router, find out how many connections each machine has open. It could be flooding your router with many small connections.

For general responsiveness, check the usual. Make sure you have enough free memory using `free -m` make sure the `top` is reasonable.

I had one old laptop, that a PCMCIA card would totally destroy any RF signal in 500m when I had it plugged in due to a driver bug.